# How I can construct the quotient group?

Tags: equivalence-relations

The motivation to this question can be found in: [How I can define an equivalence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480031/how-i-can-define-an-equivalence-relation)

My question is: How I can construct the **quotient group** related to the equivalence relation defined by copper.hat in the second comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you think an equivalence relation always gives rise to a quotient group. That is not true, by far -- it happens only when (a) the set your equivalence relation is on already has a group structure, **and** (b) the equivalence classes just happen to be the cosets of a normal subgroup.

In your previous question even condition (a) fails to hold; there isn't a group structure in sight anywhere. Therefore it doesn't give rise to any quotient group. (Or at least not in any way that is *meaningful* given what you write in the earlier question).

Comment: We can consider the group $(ℝ,+)$.

Comment: @AR1: Then condition (b) still fails spectacularly.

Comment: The equivalence class of the identity element is always a normal subgroup of the original group.

Comment: @AR1: No, that's only in very special cases where the equivalence relation is constructed in a particular way from a group homomorphism, which is not the case in your question. There _is no_ group homomorphism from $(\mathbb R,{+})$ whose image has two elements.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm: Ok and thank you very much for clarification.